# Minimal online commerce software for simple shop

Tags: php, e-commerce, online-store

I've been looking for some open source (preferably PHP) online shop software that is relatively minimal but haven't had any success. The people that I'm developing the shop for are selling a very limited selection of items and only need PayPal intergration and as such don't need all the bells and whistles of the major open source software options (Zen Cart, etc).

Does anyone have any experience with any minimal open source shop software they can recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frequently asked question.

Unfortunately there are rarely any simple requirements for e-commerce. There are just too many variables: taxes, product attributes, sub products, packaging, stock control, user account details, shopping carts, shipping methods, delivery methods, payment options, legal requirement, refunds, security methods... the list goes on.

This is why you probably won't find a package that will do exactly what you want that's simple.

But you never know. Good luck!

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't the case. I've been looking at OpenCart (http://www.opencart.com/) because of its MVC code which makes it a lot easier to modify. Time to get to work!

Comment: I read on an Australian Government Business Advisory website that setting up an e-commerce site was easy. I don't know where they got that info from. Ubercart might be a good bet. Stay the hell away from Virtuemart :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/

Is something Drupal really to complicated for you?

That makes an online shop simplicity itself

Answer (score 0):

I dont recomend drupal if you program OO.
Ive use it and its really a nightmare, the only plus it has its that its so old that there its a lot of modules and they are all free. The downers are that not all the modules all well integrated, all api its procedure (functions) oriented, there its a lot of "hacked" modules that modify others modules behaviour, modifying or trying to customize or make specific customizacion could involve a lot of time. but i guess its a disadvantage of all generic cms 
Virtuemart pluging for joomla has paypal integration, it has cms and its an Object Oriented framework with a lot of documentation. its easy to install, easoy administration, and even easy to modify.

Comment: That's interesting! Virtuemart is some of the worst software I have ever seen. But I last looked at it about 5 years ago when it had duplicated code, PHP mixed with HTML and all sorts of nasty surprises. Is it better these days?